# What is the max limit for the channels on which I can publish and subscribe?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

I have a requirement where I want to publish the data to more than 100,000 channels  and the subscribers will subscribe to whatever channels they want to.

- So I want to know is there a hard limit to the number of channels that can be available on Redis?
- If I want to benchmark the performance of Redis with all there channels and the subscribers to the channels is there any available tool that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

> So I want to know is there a hard limit to the number of channels that can be available on Redis?

In practice, there's NO limit. You can have as many channels as possible, until the memory is full.

Comment: Will the subscribers get disconnected when the memory is full?

Comment: I think the connection won't be closed, but you might not be able to publish messages.