# Multiple channel subscriptions through single 'ioredis' subscriber client

Tags: redis, nestjs, publish-subscribe, ioredis

I'm working on messaging project, where I need to have a large number of Redis PubSub channel subscriptions as shown in the graphic below . I'm on NestJS and use 'ioredis' library. I have few questions regarding this design,

[image]

1. Assuming there is only one subscriber client, do all channel subscriptions get multiplexed through a single Redis connection?
2. Is there a limit to how many channel subscriptions a client can have assuming Redis cluster is able to scale.

Thanks.

Comment: follow the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664313/what-is-the-max-limit-for-the-channels-on-which-i-can-publish-and-subscribe. There is not limit.

Comment: Thanks, @Dai. I was more interested in how the client was handling it.